# How to view annotated powerpoint presentations in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice, presentation, annotation, microsoft-powerpoint

I have some `.pptx` presentation files, which were annotated with a stylus in an online class. These annotations do not show up in LibreOffice Impress 7.0.3.1 in Xubuntu 20.04 (I am using the LibreOffice Fresh PPA).

1. Is there any way to see these annotations with LibreOffice?
2. If not, can they be viewed with any other free (as in freedom) software?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ONLYOFFICE](https://www.onlyoffice.com/) claims to be higly compatible with MS Office formats, and it is released under AGPL.
There are many ways to install it in Ubuntu, use your favourite method.

It is a bit slow to start (this is not a snap only issue, even the .deb package takes a lot of time to start compared to libreoffice), but successfully loads annotated powerpoint presentations (verified by OP).

**Snap Package**

ONLYOFFICE is available as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/onlyoffice-desktopeditors) and can be installed with

```
snap install onlyoffice-desktopeditors
```

**Debian package**

A [`.deb`-package](https://www.onlyoffice.com/download.aspx?from=downloadintegrationmenu) is also available.

**Flatpak**

Use the following commands to install it with [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.onlyoffice.desktopeditors).

```
flatpak install flathub org.onlyoffice.desktopeditors
```

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with ONLYOFFICE in any way.

Answer (score 3):

The answers will not be to your liking:

1. Nope.
2. They can be viewed with [O365’s online version of PowerPoint](https://www.microsoft.com/en/microsoft-365/free-office-online-for-the-web) for “free”, but not as free as you are asking