# Will Office Home & Student 2019 work on Ubuntu + QEMU?

Tags: qemu

I have used Virtual Machine Manager QEMU / KVM very smoothly to run Windows 10 from Ubuntu, programs and everything else seem to work in virtual Windows without any problem.

I am considering buying a copy of Office 2019 (which is the only non-Linux program I need and have no alternative for). Will it work on Qemu? How can I know before paying?

Comment: If you have Windows installed, all software should work there.

Comment: It works fine on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTE running QEMU > Windows 10 Home. I don't have sound from the VM, but that is not a problem for my Office needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to know before paying. Download a trail version of [Office 365](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/try), and check if it works. Since Windows 10 is working, I see no reason why Office would not work.

However, you can also look for alternatives

1. Microsoft Office Online is available for free. It allows to view as well as edit and save files. You can create a shortcut and use it as a standalone web app.
2. Some FOSS alternatives like [OnlyOffice](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299805/124466) have a high compatibility with Microsoft office files. For example, it correctly shows annotations made with a stylus, which LibreOffice cannot show.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Microsoft or OnlyOffice

Answer (score 1):

It will run on a Windows 10 VM running under QEMU, but performance can vary based on specs of you machine and you also need a W10 licence as well to run this way. I would test to see how the Windows 10 runs on you hardware first before buying Office.

Also consider using VirtualBox instead of QEMU as after installing the tools on the Windows VM you can run in seamless mode with the Windows apps and Linux apps running on the same desktop.

Of course you could always try the web 365 apps in fullscreen mode in your browser, you lose some functionality but is totally fine for most uses.